# php get first and second word after (at)

Tags: php

I need some help with a php code which torment me 2-3 hours. Ny methods tried but no result. I want to take the first and second word after the @, eg **@John Doe** and php result took me John and Doe

I thing something that: 
(Edited)

```
$q = 'Hi @Stefan Simeonov kak si? @Krasi avramov';
    if (preg_match_all("(@[^ ]+[ ][^ ]+)", $q, $match)) {
        foreach ($match[0] as $singleMatch) {
           $finded[] = $singleMatch; 
           $success = 1;
        }
    } elseif (preg_match_all("(@[^ ]+)", $q, $match)) {
        foreach ($match[0] as $singleMatch) {
            $finded[] = $singleMatch; 
            $success = 1;
        }
    } else {
        $success = 0;
    }

    if($success = 1) {
        $replace = $q;
        foreach ($finded as $user) {
            $expl = explode("@",$user);
            $rep = '<a href="?profile='.$expl[1].'">'.$expl[1].'</a>';
            $replace = str_replace($user,$rep,$replace);
        }
        echo $replace;
    } else {
        echo $q;
    }
```

Comment: You need to add some code indicating where you possibly went wrong, and what is the result you expect.

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Can there be multiple @... in one string?

Answer (score 3):

Using a regular expression for example:

```
<?php
$q = 'Hi @John Doe kak si?';

if (preg_match('/@(\w+)\s(\w+)/', $q, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

This will look for a word after a `@`, followed by a space, followed by another word.

Comment: This output: Array ( [0] => @John Doe [1] => John [2] => Doe )
I'm not sure if OP wants to have @ in output.

Comment: @Adam Then the OP just needs to use `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<?
$q = 'Hi @John Doe kak si?';
$explodeTab = explode("@",$q);
$words = explode(" ",$explodeTab[1]);
print_r($words);
?>
```

**[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/fdlv8NMn)**

Comment: This is the best method

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex of `(@[^ ]+[ ][^ ]+)` for this:

```
<?php
    $q = 'Hi @Stefan Simeonov kak si?';
    if (preg_match_all("(@[^ ]+[ ][^ ]+)", $q, $match)) {
        foreach ($match[0] as $singleMatch) {
            echo 'Found match: ' . $singleMatch . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
?>
```

Will output:

> Found match: @Stefan Simeonov

Comment: `[ ]` → just a space; no need to make a character group for a single character.

Comment: @deceze I know - it's pure readability *for me*. That way I can skim the code and know that I did it on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that words are always separated by spaces, you can achieve this by first splitting the input string on the `@` character and then taking the 1th item and splitting that on the space character and reducing that result to the words that you need.

```
<?php
$q = 'Hi @John Doe kak si?';
$atSplitResult = explode('@', $q);
$spaceSplitResult = explode(' ', $atSplitResult[1]);
$firstTwoWords = array_slice($spaceSplitResult, 0, 2);

var_dump($firstTwoWords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, we have a sentence

*Let's see, @mike, how are you doing?*

now:

```
$atExploded = explode('@', $str); //where $str is our string
if(count($atExploded)){
  foreach($atExploded as $at){
    $spaceExplode = explode(' ', $at);
    echo $spaceExplode[0].' '.$spaceExplode[1]; //after checking that [0] and [1] are reachable
  }
}
```

of course you should cut any unwanted characters (like braces, colons and so on) but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
$string = 'Hi @John Doe kak si?';
$regex = preg_match("/@(.+?)\s(.+?)\s/", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Returns

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "@John Doe " [1]=> string(4) "John" [2]=> string(3) "Doe" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this. This will output @John Doe

```
<?php
$q = 'Hi @John Doe kak si?';
$q = preg_match('/@[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+/', $q, $match);
print_r($match);

?>
```